# Try-Catch std::bad_alloc outside function?

Tags: c++, class, try-catch, new-operator, allocation

I have:

```
class image {
public:
    linked_list<int, int> UnLabeledList;

    explicit image(int Segments) {//some code}
};
```

Where the C'tor of linked list is:

```
linked_list() {
    total_nodes = 0;
    first = new node<S, T>{}; //Dummy
    first->height = NOT_INIT;
    last = first;
}
```

How can I detect if this line fails? `linked_list<int, int> UnLabeledList;`

it's outside any function so I can't do try and catch...

Comment: You can use a function-try-block _"...A function-try-block associates a sequence of catch clauses with the entire function body, and with the __member initializer list__ (if used in a constructor)..."_  see the examples here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function-try-block

Answer (score 0):

In this example, you don't need to detect the exception in the `image` constructor at all. The exception will cancel the construction of the `UnLabeledList` member, which is running during the `image` constructor's member initialization, before the body of the `image` constructor is entered. Any other `image` members that were created successfully before the exception is thrown will be destroyed automatically.

The exception will be thrown into the code that is constructing the `image` object. You can use a `try/catch` in that code, if needed.

If you absolutely need to catch the exception inside the constructor of `image` (which is *extremely rare* in properly written code), you can use a [function-try](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function-try-block) around the constructor's [member initialization list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor), eg:

```
class image {
public:
    linked_list<int, int> UnLabeledList;

    explicit image(int Segments) try : UnLabeledList() {
        // some normal code...
    } catch (...) {
        // some error handling code...
    } // <-- exception is automatically rethrown here!
};
```